# jQuery - Sorting div contents

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: Sort div's according to content of different sub divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501789/jquery-sort-divs-according-to-content-of-different-sub-divs)

Is it possible to sort the contents of div

```
<div id="sort">
    <div id="something">A2</div>
    <div id="something">A1</div>
    <div id="something">A4</div>
    <div id="something">A3</div>
</div>
```

sorted to:

```
<div id="sort">
    <div id="something">A1</div>
    <div id="something">A2</div>
    <div id="something">A3</div>
    <div id="something">A4</div>
</div>
```

Anything like this????

```
$('#sort').sort();
```

Comment: Element id's should be unique.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about this?

```
var mylist = $('#sort');

var listitems = mylist.children('div').get();

listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
});

$.each(listitems, function(index, item) {
   mylist.append(item); 
});
```

Pulled from: http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

And This: [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Comment: Cool! works great! (except a semicolon missing on listitem.sort() function

Comment: Confirmed, works great.