# Problem using .sort to sort elements alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am having a problem with sorting using jquery.The elements not getting sorted.I used javascript .sort but this works fine with me if the attribute is numbers but not text.
I can solve the issue using append but this is not what am willing to use.
Can some one please trouble shoot this code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var divList = $(".listing-item");
  var gg = divList.get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data("listing-title") < $(b).data("listing-title");
  });
  console.log(gg);
  $("#list").html(divList);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="a">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="z">
    z
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="b">
    b
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="c">
    c
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for the `.sort()` callback. It must return a number to indicate how the two compared elements should be ordered; your callback returns a boolean (`true` or `false`), and that won't work.

Comment: @Pointy do you have a suggestion for how to solve such an issue?

Comment: Yes, write a proper sort comparator. The simplest thing to do is to use the string `.localeCompare()` method to compare two strings. It returns exactly the sort of numeric result you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.localeCompare()`. I have pull this working content from [jQuery - Sorting div contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433871/jquery-sorting-div-contents)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htm>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var divList = $(".listing-item");
   divList.sort(function(a, b) {
    return  $(a).data("listing-title").toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).data("listing-title").toUpperCase());
});
   $("#list").html(divList);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="list">
     <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="a">a</div>
     <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="z">z</div>
     <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="b">b</div>
     <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="c">c</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See also similar question [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Comment: Thank you ,this solve the issue.but can you describe  why you used toUppercase

Answer (score 0):

you just need to return a number in the sorting function. Return -1 if the first should be placed before the second. So sort ascending

You can add more conditions.

`if($(a).data("listing-title") > $(b).data("listing-title"))  return 1` -> descending
`if($(a).data("listing-title") = $(b).data("listing-title"))  return 0` -> no sorting

and put in the HTML the sorted list ( `gg` instead of `divList`)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var divList = $(".listing-item");
  var gg = divList.get().sort(function(a, b) {
    if($(a).data("listing-title") < $(b).data("listing-title")) {
    return -1 ;
    }
  });
  console.log(gg);
  $("#list").html(gg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="a">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="z">
    z
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="b">
    b
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item" data-listing-title="c">
    c
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need jQuery for this, and I think the problem is your comparison function, something like this, should make the job for you:

```
//First select the items
const items = document.querySelectorAll('div#list > .listing-item');
//Next, transform this to an array using `from`, then compare
//using `sort`, finally iterate over the sorted array using `forEach`,
//and append element in the sorted array to the `#list`.
//
Array
  .from(items)
  .sort((x,y) => {
    const valueX = x.dataset.listingTitle;
    const valueY = y.dataset.listingTitle;

    if(valueX > valueY) return 1;
    else if(valueX < valueY) return -1;
    else return 0;
  })
  .forEach(element => document.getElementById('list').appendChild(element));
```